# How to achieve this kind of "peeling" effect at the bottom of the page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, dictionary

I'm trying to achieve the same effect as [on this website](http://www.egotribe.nl) (if you scroll down to the bottom of the page you will see the map appearing with a kind of "peeling effect", like if the previous DIVs was sliding above the map). I tried to replicate this in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GJ55B/ (with a red div instead of map) but I must be missing something since it does not work. 
Thanks for your help

[image: What I would like to achieve, to see in live]
HTML

```
<div class="block">Block</div>
<div class="block">Block</div>
<div class="block">Block</div>
<div class="block">Block</div>
<div class="block">Block</div>
<div id="map"><div id="map-canvas"></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
Html, body {
    min-width: 980px;
    background: #CCC;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;


}
.block {    
    padding: 20px;
    background: green;
    height: 400px;
    width: 600px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left:50px;
}

#map {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#map, #map-canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    float: left;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uN82H/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="block a"></div>
    <div class="block b"></div>
    <div class="block c"></div>
</div>
<div id="map">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container{
    margin-bottom:300px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
.block{
    height:300px;
}
.a{background:tomato;}
.b{background:gold;}
.c{background:#4c5660;}
#map{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
    height:400px;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/700/400/) bottom center no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the demo! The issue with this solution (in my case) is that I need the blocks to have a width set in % (i.e. 75%). Only the map div needs 100% width so if I set the block width to 75% in your demo the picture gets visible in the back while a scroll down. Is there a workaround? Thanks

Comment: Wonderful! Appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi - actually i tried in real environment (see http://goo.gl/F8ciEs ) and for some reason the z-index does not seem to be working (picture is always on top). Any thoughts on that? Many thanks

Comment: @Greg: put the map outside the `fullcontainer`

Answer (score 1):

The map is simply set to `position:fixed;bottom:0;width:100%`. This makes it "stuck" to the bottom.

Next, the content area is given a `z-index` higher than the map, to make it appear on top.

Then, the last section of the content has `margin-bottom:500px`, allowing the element to scroll that much further to reveal the map.